# How shall i integrate my android apps with google Account

Tags: android, gmail

Greetings to all!!!!

My Requirement is:
  As Soon as i open My application it should redirect to Google Log in Page first.
  After entering user name and password in Google sign in page it should enter into my android application.And importantly it should not enter into Google inbox.

Eg For My logic is:

As simple like our Stack-overflow log in....if we already log in in Google just clicking on Google,it will takes to stack overflow and not to Google page.

Since i dont even have a single clue i was failed to start.

So some one please pay attention on my Requirements.
Thanks for your attention
And Thanks in advance for the Helping Hearts.

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html

Comment: Get a `WebView` and open respective url for google sign in in it.simple.

Comment: @ Soumil Deshpande Hi thanks for your response..I already have that project with me...But that is not the thing which i want....My need is instead of creating our own login i want to use google login but it should works like user created login page....that is while running my code it should display google login but once we enter user name and password and login means it should login to my android apps and not into google...hope i'm not confusing you